# Determine average for vector with different factors

Tags: r

Say I have an "integer" factor vector of length 5:

```
vecFactor = c(1,3,2,2,3)
```

and another "integer" data vector of length 5:

```
vecData = c(1.3,4.5,6.7,3,2)
```

How can I find the average of the data in each factor, so that I would get a result of:

```
Factor 1: Average = 1.3
Factor 2: Average = 4.85
Factor 3: Average = 3.25
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 tapply(vecData, vecFactor, FUN=mean)
   1    2    3 
 1.30 4.85 3.25
```

Comment: @Jiber Thanks, that is a huge list. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I sometimes use a linear model to do this instead of tapply, which is quite flexible (for instance if you need to add weights...). Don't forget the "-1" in the formula

```
lm(vecData~factor(vecFactor)-1)$coef

factor(vecFactor)1 factor(vecFactor)2 factor(vecFactor)3
        1.30               4.85               3.25
```

Comment: which also has the advantage of avoiding the "what's wrong? oh wait forgot the na.rm=T" part)

Answer (score 1):

To get a good table, try aggregate function with data.frame:

```
ddf = data.frame(vecData, vecFactor)
aggregate(vecData~vecFactor, data=ddf, mean)
  vecFactor vecData
1         1    1.30
2         2    4.85
3         3    3.25
```

data.table can also be used for this:

```
library(data.table)    
ddt = data.table(ddf)
ddt[,list(meanval=mean(vecData)),by=vecFactor]
   vecFactor meanval
1:         1    1.30
2:         3    3.25
3:         2    4.85
```